# How to train the same Keras LSTM model with multiple same structured datasets?

Tags: keras, time-series, concatenation, lstm, ensemble-learning

Consider typical LSTM model for time series problem. If i want to train the model with different datasets, what should I do? I must create one model and train it with 120 different datasets but same size, same time steps, same features. Model must consider all of those datasets to predict afterwards.

Consider the typical LSTM structure below:

```
model_seq = Sequential()
model_seq.add(InputLayer((5,4)))
model_seq.add(LSTM(64))
model_seq.add(Dense(8,"relu"))
model_seq.add(Dense(1,"linear"))
```

And compiling like below:

```
opti=rp(learning_rate=0.0001)
opti2=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model_seq.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opti,metrics="mae")
model_seq.fit(x1,y1,epochs=5, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
```

My problem is I don't want to train with only x1-y1. I also need to train the same model with x2-y2,x3-y3 etc. At the end, I need one model that understood all of 120 datasets behavior and it must be able to predict another x-y data. Is it possible? Your comments will be very important because I couldn't do it for very long time.
Thanks.

When I try to fit multiple times, model only consider last fitting. Because all time series starts with 0 and ends at different values.

Comment: Just put everything into one dataset?

Comment: How? For example for one data, I have (17656,5,4) shaped input and (17651,) shaped output. When I train the LSTM with only whis information, it is ok. But I have several of them. If I just stack them like you say, shape of the input becomes (126,17651,5,4) and shape of the output becomes (126,17651,). So, how can I feed the LSTM with this structure. If you know, please share with me. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: And can I use TimeDistributed layer for this case. If yes, please guide me about it.